# extra character on reading the csv header

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read the header of the csv in python:

code:

```
for each_file in listdir(mypath):
with open(mypath +"//"+each_file) as f:
    first_line = f.readline().strip().split(",")
    print (first_line)
    break
```

Expected_op:

```
["A","B"] (or) ['A' ,'B']
```

my op:

```
['"A"', '"B"']
```

Any suggestions on correcting this?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: I mean.. it does include desired behavior, no..? (Under "Expected_op")

Comment: Show the file. The header part.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, the solution is perfect. But I was assuming I am making some mistake in the read file code. Will use this anyway. N yeah thumbs up to the downvoters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume original CSV file has strings `"A","B"` ? In this case quotations will be included as well. If you wish to avoid them, you need to include `.replace()` function:

```
first_line = f.readline().strip().replace('"', '').split(",")
```